# Using PHPUnit in Zend Studio on a remote server

Tags: php, phpunit, zend-studio

I develop on a Windows machine using Zend Studio but my dev server is a centOS server on the local network.  I've been running my unit tests through putty but it would be really nice if I could configure Zend to run my unit tests through my dev server just for convenience sake.  I've looked around in Zend's settings but I can't find anything that references where to run the tests.

Does anyone know where I can start or can anyone point me to some resources that can help me set this up?

Thanks,

Jordan

Comment: Which Zend Studio version?

Comment: Version 10.5.  I know it just came out, so that may make it trickier.

Comment: Haven't tried that one yet. 
However, you should create a Remote Project through SSH or FTP and run the tests there.

Comment: I tried that but after clicking "Run As >> PHPUnit Test" it sits there and does nothing until I cancel it.  If I run the same test over ssh through putty the test finishes in less than a second.